# ipfs-update isn't showing the expected version list

Tags: go, ipfs

I ran

```
go get -u github.com/ipfs/ipfs-update
```

and got in the end of what it looks like an installation going on the following

> go get: installing executables with 'go get' in module mode is deprecated.
>
> Use 'go install pkg@version' instead.
>
> For more information, see https://golang.org/doc/go-get-install-deprecation or run 'go help get' or 'go help install'.
>
> github.com/ipfs/ipfs-update
>
> go/pkg/mod/github.com/ipfs/ipfs-update@v1.7.1/main.go:318:21: cannot use lib.NewIpfsFetcher(distPath, 0) (type *lib.IpfsFetcher) as type migrations.Fetcher in argument to migrations.NewMultiFetcher:
>
> *lib.IpfsFetcher does not implement migrations.Fetcher (missing Close method)

[image]

Then, used

```
ipfs-update versions
```

but didn't see the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get that working I've used instead

```
go install github.com/ipfs/ipfs-update@latest
```

Then once running

```
ipfs-update versions
```

I got

[image]

Then could simply run

```
ipfs-update install v0.11.0
```

[image]